# Separate a characters string in CSV

Tags: php, string, excel, csv, web-scraping

I would like to separate the characters of a string in excel. For the moment I have a list like this in CSV.

For example in A1 :

```
Uncle Tony Records,Florida,"Electronic, Indie, Weird & Unusual"
```

I would like for all the entries of my list to be:

```
A1 Uncle Tony Records B1 Florida  C1 Electronic, Indie, Weird & Unusual
```

Comment: look into php's built-in csv functions, such as this one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: The thing is I would like to do this directly in EXCEL! Thanks

Comment: if you have a csv file, you should be able to just open it in excel. what else is needed here?

Comment: Sure, but i want to separates the string in 3 in one function, I have a list for 1000 strings...

Comment: i don't see a reason to do this in excel, especially when you're already using php to scrape the data. just use php to create the .csv file formatted how you want, then open it in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command :

```
array str_getcsv ( string $input [, string $delimiter = ',' [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = '\\' ]]] )
```

Comment: I will try directyl with php then. THX

Comment: Try and give example .. copy and paste from `PHP doc` is not a good way to answer a question.